# Change default data source encoding in QGIS to utf8

Tags: qgis, csv, import, encoding, utf-8

Working in languages with special characters, I always struggle with remembering to change the data source encoding from *system* to *utf8* when I import files. Is there a way to have it automatically use utf8 instead of system, or maybe changing the data source encoding of system to utf8?

Answer (score 11):

From `Settings >> Data Sources >> Data source handling`, you may try to uncheck the `Ignore shapefile encoding declaration` option.

If you move the mouse cursor over the above option, this message appears:

> *Disable OGR on-the-fly conversion from declared encoding to UTF-8*

Comment: Should be marked as 'Best answer'

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.18.1-Zürich and don't have the `Ignore shapefile encoding declaration` under `Data source handling`.